# EntityFramework SqlQuery and Reflection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection

I have been trying to generate a SiteMap for multiple websites for a custom CMS that I am writing.

My situation is as follows:
I have a class in an Assembly called `SiteMapItem`:

```
public abstract class SiteMapItem
{
    public abstract string Url { get; }
}
```

I have three separate classes in a different Assembly that extend `SiteMapItem`:

```
public class Team : SiteMapItem
{ ... }

public class Partner : SiteMapItem
{ ... }

public class Project : SiteMapItem
{ ... }
```

In the Assembly that is going to generate the SiteMap, I am running the following code to get a list of the Types that have `IsSubClassOf(typeof(SiteMapItem))`:

```
foreach (Assembly a in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
{
    if (a.GetTypes().Any(t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(SiteMapItem))))
    {
        winner = a;
    }
}
```

Once I have Winner, I get a list of Types that have the `IsSubClassOf` `SiteMapItem`:

```
List<Type> types = winner.GetTypes().Where(p => p.IsSubclassOf(typeof(SiteMapItem))).ToList();
```

I then Iterate over `types` to run the `db.Database.SqlQuery` - which is where I am stuck (db is a DataContext):

```
var items = db.Database.SqlQuery(t, "SELECT * FROM @table", new SqlParameter("table", t.Name"));
```

The above code returns nothing, When debugging, the type is set correctly for each iteration, However when I inspect `items`, and try to evaluate results, I get the error `Children could not be evaluated`.

I would normally use the alternative:

```
db.Database.SqlQuery<T>("SELECT * FROM @fdsfdsa", ...)
```

but because I don't have a Class (Its in another assembly) I cannot.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you're not swallowing an exception? I get `Must declare the table variable "@table".`, which means that the statement expects a table variable and can't handle *schema tables* in this way.

Comment: I have tried it this way and also hard coded the table name in. Makes no difference. The only exception that I am swollowing is a reflection exception about mscorlib not having a getter for some property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code

```
var items = db.Database.SqlQuery(t, "SELECT * FROM @table", new SqlParameter("table", t.Name"));
```

returns DbRawSqlQuery not rows.

you need to access by

```
items.GetEnumerator
```

Comment: How could I miss something so simple. Many thanks :)